# React-Native redux form package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

while looking for solution for working with redux-form for react-native, I came across this [link](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/react-native.html)

but the problem is I cannot find the package in the npm registry when I "yarn add react-redux-form/native"

Can anyone help with how to go about using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add `react-redux-form` package. `/native` refers to a file or a sub-directory in that main package.

Do `yarn add react-redux-form` and then `import { Control } from 'react-redux-form/native';` should just work fine.